# Rasterizing misaligned grids [r - terra]

Tags: r, rasterization, terra

I'm working with satellite data and trying to convert it to a raster in R. The downloaded product from NASA was vectorized on their end which is frustrating. The problem is that the satellite is taking a curved orbit, and therefor the path is not parallel to the equator or prime meridian leading to gaps in the data when rasterizing. I'm attempting to retain the original resolution of the data, and rasterizing the data of grid over the study area with that resolution leads to the following moire pattern with terra::rasterize (using fun = "count"). Ideally this plot should be uniformly 1's or with sparse 2's.

[image: Example moire pattern using fun = "count" when rasterizing]

I know that I can decrease the number of grid cells, but in order to remove these artifacts, I have to reduce the number of cells by nearly 50% for each axis. Krigging or interpolation are also not suitable as these data has missing values by design.

Any ideas for how to rasterize these data more effectively? I was thinking about using terra::spin to align the data to the grid before I rasterize, but then I don't now how I'd undo that transformation after it has been rasterized. I was also thinking about making some sort of crazy CRS that follows the original path of the satellite, but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out that the sensor "pixels" on the satellite are not evenly spaced on the Y axis. Not sure why this is the case.

I was able to use nearest neighbor interpolation to fill in these gaps.

e.g.

```
library(terra)
library(collapse) #collapse::fmode function faster than terra::modal
raster <- focal(raster, matrix(1, 3, 3), fmode, ties = "first") #nearest neighbor interpolation)
```